# Using BeautifulSoup to parse some HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following section of html, it is a section of a page that displays results from a football game.

```
<div class = "schedules-list-matchup"></div>
<!-- <un inportant stuff  -->
<div class=list-matchup-row-team>
    <span class="team-name away lost">team1</span>
    <span class="team-logo away team-name">...</span>
    <span class="team-score away lost">2</span>
    <span class="team-score home">3</span>
    <span class="team-logo home team-name">...</span>
    <span class="team-name home">team2</span>
</div>
<div class=list-matchup-row-team>
    <span class="team-name away lost">team3</span>
    <span class="team-logo away team-name">...</span>
    <span class="team-score away lost">2</span>
    <span class="team-score home">3</span>
    <span class="team-logo home team-name">...</span>
    <span class="team-name home">team4</span>
</div>
<!-- <ramainder of code> -->
```

I am trying to read it in and create objects of class:

```
class Game:
def __init__(self, homeTeam, homeTeamScore, awayTeam, awayTeamScore):
    self.homeTeam = homeTeam
    self.homeTeamScore = homeTeamScore
    self.awayTeam = awayTeam
    self.awayTeamScore = awayTeamScore
```

what i thought i was doing was iterating over each`<div class= "list-matchup-row-team>`

my code:

```
html = urlopen(baseUrl + '1')
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
table = bsObj.find("ul",{"class":"schedules-table"})

for game in table.findAll("li", {"class":"schedules-list-matchup"}):
    for g in game.findAll("div", {"class":"list-matchup-row-team"}):
        for teams in g.findAll("span", {"class" : "home"}):
            print(teams.find("span", {"class" : "team-name"}))
            print(teams.find("span", {"class" : "team-score"}))

    print('==========================')
```

which returns a bunch of null objects. 
how could i iterate over each span element inside the `<div class= "list-matchup-row-team>` tag and check if the class contains both 'team-name' and 'team-score'? for each home and away?

Comment: Why can't you just get all elements with home then all elements with away?

Comment: I can, but once i have all the home elements, how can i further separate them out  to save each piece of data to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just approach team-name class directly.

try this.

```
table.findAll("span", {"class" : "team-name"})
```

then pick up away and home.

Comment: if i 'for game in table.findAll("li", {"class":"schedules-list-matchup"}):
  for g in game.findAll("div", {"class":"list-matchup-row-team"}):
   for teamNames in g.findAll("span", {"class" : "team-name"}):
    print(teamNames.find("span", {"class" : "home"}))', then i still get a none object back.

Comment: I mean you don't need all other findAll stuff. just table.findAll("span", {"class": "team-name"}) is okay to look up in html.